# state changing twice react

Tags: reactjs, state

good afternoon
I have a component where I select a value.
I control the value of that component with a state and to change that state I pass a function to the component. From the moment I change the state of this component, it changes twice, the state triggers the ID and immediately afterwards the ID becomes zero.

```
 const [currency, setCurrency] = useState('');

 const handleChange = (event) => {
    setCurrency(event.target.value);
  };

  <TextField
    select
    value={state}
    onChange={handleChange}
    margin="normal"
    helperText="Selection value"
    fullWidth
  >
    {optionsAPI.map((option) => (
      <MenuItem key={option.id} value={option.id}>
          {option.descrition}
      </MenuItem>
    ))}
  </TextField>
```

Comment: TextField is User Defined component or React native componet?

Comment: Can you try by removing value attribute from textfield once I guess it's happening because of that. Or try onchange= {()=>handlechange(event)}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passing `state` which is undefined  as a value to `value` props.
`currency` should be passed instead.

```
<TextField
        select
        value={currency} // not state.
        onChange={handleChange}
        margin="normal"
        helperText="Selection value"
        fullWidth
      >
```

Also, you have to stop `event bubbling`.

```
const handleChange = (event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    setCurrency(event.target.value);
  };
```